# Error Python instalación paquete distribuible

Tags: python, modulos

tengo este problema  no puedo instalar el paquete distribuible para este programa de Python, me sale un error que dice ***pip3 : El término 'pip3' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó***
una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
Alguien me podría decir donde esta el error ?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**adjunto la carpeta donde los archivos**

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lRGH8n1L__QAIro4YwjYWEcZRv_Z0co2

Comment: Muestra un [repro] _en la pregunta_, no enlaces archivos externos. Lee [ask].

Comment: Claro es que necesito poder compartir toda la carpeta para que puedan ver los archivos por eso pase el link de drive

Comment: eso puede deberse a 2 cosas, 1. No tienes pip agregado al paht o 2. si no tienes otra version de python (python 2.x) no es necesario que pongas `pip3`